# How do I boot an Android S8 that is out of memory

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have an Android S8 that is out of memory and will not start completely.
I've already switched over to a new phone for daily use.

It will start and boot to the main screen for under a minute, then goes into a boot loop.

There are text message threads that I need for business and legal reasons, and I need them exactly as they are.  When I synced (inexact term) my new S21, I only got the receiver side of the messages, my side was not restored.